# implicit types in xkb

Tags: x11, xkb, setxkbmap

The keymap source (in .xkb format) of the current XKB configuration can be obtained by running `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -`.  Mapping to keysyms is done in the `xkb_symbols` section of this file.  Some of the definitions in this section explicitly define the key `type`, which indicates which modifiers index the various `keysym` levels; for example:

```
key <AD01> {type= "ALPHABETIC", [q, Q]};
```

Other lines do not specify their type; for example:

```
key <AE01> {[1, exclam]};
```

In this case, the type is ambiguous, as there are multiple two-level types defined in the `xkb_types` section of this file (TWO_LEVEL, ALPHABETIC, KEYPAD, SHIFT+ALT, PC_SUPER_LEVEL2, etc.).  Hence, there must be implicit (or default) types for a given number of levels (e.g., an implicit two-level type when no type is given but two levels are present).  Where are these implicit types defined?  Is it simply the first type appearing in `xkb_types` that has the requisite number of levels?

Answer (score 2):

The defaults are specified in the [The X Keyboard Extension: Protocol Specification](https://www.x.org/docs/XKB/XKBproto.pdf) for X11R6.4 in section 12.2.3 (pp. 41-42) and Appendix B.  Specifically, ONE_LEVEL, TWO_LEVEL, ALPHABETIC, and KEYPAD are considered canonical types, and are selected, after alphanumeric expansion, in accordance with the following criteria:

> For each keyboard group that does not have an explicit type definition, XKB chooses a key type from the canonical key types. If the second symbol assigned to a group is NoSymbol (after alphabetic expansion), the server assigns key type ONE_LEVEL. If the group contains the lowercase and uppercase forms of a single glyph (after alphanumeric expansion), the server assigns key type ALPHABETIC. If either of the symbols in a group is a numeric keypad keysym (KP_*), the server assigns key type KEYPAD. Otherwise, it assigns key type TWO_LEVEL.

The protocol does not specify canonical types for groups having more than two levels.